# How to get broweser name when each thread in parallel test execution with multiple browsers in TestNG, Cucumber and Selenide

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, testng, selenide

Is there a way to get the current browser name of each thread running using Selenide?
I integrated TestNG Cucumber with multiple browsers.
So I need to know at **@After** hook, which browser is running the test.
And based on browser do some stuff.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="8" parallel="tests" >
    <test name="ChromeTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.site.runner.TestRunner">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="FirefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.site.runner.TestRunner">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="SafariTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="safari" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.site.runner.TestRunner">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Selenide set driver

```
public static synchronized void setDriver(String browser) {
        setBrowser(browser);
    }

public String setBrowser(String browser){

        switch(browser){
            case "chrome":
                return setCapabilities(browser);
            case "firefox":
                return Configuration.browser = "firefox";
            case "edge":
                return Configuration.browser = "edge";
            default:
                return "No Browser found";
        }

public static void directToBrowserUrl(String browserUrl) {
        open(browserUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of creating WebDriver?

Comment: @NandanA Added the WebDriver code snippet

Comment: Is solution working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `capabilities` and `current thread` of the `driver` in **`@After`** method.

**Code:**

```
 Capabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = capabilities.getBrowserName();
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    
    System.out.println("Thread name & browser name: "+threadName +" --> "+browserName);
    System.out.println("Thread id & browser name: "+threadId +" --> "+browserName);

    if(browserName.equalsIngnoreCase("Chrome"){
     //do your stuff
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Thread name & browser name: com.CallerScript.Caller.main() --> chrome
Thread id & browser name: 16 --> chrome
```

Comment: Since I used selenide I did below
`Capabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver) WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver()).getCapabilities();`